# I can’t get a teleport to work c#

Tags: unity, c#

[image: pacmaninspect]
[image: lightinspect]
[image: camerainspect]
[image: bodyinspect]
these are the pics of the inspect panel on the parts of the 3D pacman that you asked for.

(I just added these photos because I couldn’t while i was away and because even though the advice given so far was amazing, it didn’t resolve my problem, so please help if you can)

I’ve been trying to make a teleport for a while and it works only part of the time. the collisions work because i put a debug.log in it but the teleporting part doesn’t work. there are no errors in the collision, it just doesn’t teleport the pieces of pacman. here is the script (it's not the most improved but i was trying to make it work)

```
public GameObject pacman;
public GameObject Camera;
public GameObject pointLight;
public GameObject body;
public Vector3 pacmantele;
public Vector3 cameratele;
public Vector3 pointlighttele;
public Vector3 bodytele;


void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log("works");
    pacman.transform.position = pacmantele;
    Camera.transform.position = cameratele;
    pointLight.transform.position = pointlighttele;
    body.transform.position = bodytele;
}
```

---

here is a photo of the inspection panel on the non-working teleporter

[image: the inspection panel on the non-working teleporter]

Comment: Can you show us how you've configured one of your non-working teleporters in the Inspector? And also how you've configured the entities it's teleporting?

Comment: From where do you get the member variables you use? Can you put the values of the properties of the used member-variables into the log?

Answer (score 1):

[The `OnTriggerEnter` method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) usually needs to know what entered it. So the correct form for that method is this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
```

If you forget the parameter `Collider other`, Unity will not recognize it as an event handler for the TriggerEnter event.

Further, keep in mind that this method will be called for *any* game-object that enters the teleporter. Sometimes that's intended, but usually you want to have *some* condition on what can and can not trigger a trigger.

In this case the logic seems to be written specifically for the object `pacman`, so it seems like you only want to execute that teleportation logic if `pacman` entered the trigger. So I added a check which makes sure only `packman` will trigger this teleporter:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log("Object " + other.name + " entered the teleporter");
    if (other.gameObject == pacman)
    {
        pacman.transform.position = pacmantele;
        Camera.transform.position = cameratele;
        pointLight.transform.position = pointlighttele;
        body.transform.position = bodytele;
    }
}
```

If it still does not work, make sure that:

- `pacman` has a collider which is **not** a trigger.
- `pacman` has a [rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html). If you don't actually want rigidbody physics in your game, make it a kinematic rigidbody.
- That its [physics layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) collides with the physics layer of the teleporter
- That both teleporter and pacman have any of the regular colliders, not a collider of the 2D family, because 2d and 3d colliders do not interact with each other. If you actually want to use 2D physics, use the method [`OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) and use Rigidbody2D instead of Rigidbody.